# Numpy indices: Crop rectangle from matrix with overlap / region of interest bigger than image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I want to perform random crops of a fixed rectangle size on images of varying size. This means that the crop might overlap the image on every side. I want to do this using slicing, i.e. I want to precompute the index range for both the image (src matrix) and the crop (dst matrix) , for performance.

```
crop = np.zeros((crop_size_x, crop_size_y, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
x_min_dst = ???
x_max_dst = ???
x_min_src = ???
x_max_src = ???
[...] # same for y
crop[x_min_dst:x_max_dst, y_min_dst:y_max_dst, :] = image[x_min_src:x_max_src,y_min_src:y_max_src, :]
```

If someone knows a solution to this, please let me know, otherwise I will try to come up with a solution myself and post it here. Maybe there is already a function in numpy or opencv that does this?

This drawing should clarify the problem (only overlap in x dimension considered, y-dimension should be analogous):

[image]

Comment: Can't you just limit range of `x` like: `x = max(min(x, width), 0)`

Comment: I guess this would limit x to lie within the boundaries of the image to be cropped. However crops should be of fixed size and may lie outside the image

Comment: What do you expect the pixel values outside the image to be? How about padding the input image?

Comment: 2D padding, would be slow (the function is called very frequently on CPU), therefore I'd rather like to compute the index range and perform slicing (hopefully faster than padding)

Comment: Let’s say your image is shape(5,7) and you want your total crop to be shape(5,5). How are you determining where the horizontal slice is coming from? i.e. will it be [:,1:6] from the original image or zeros for the left or right 3 columns with the values [:,:2] for right padded or [:,:-2] for left padded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my current solution:

```
crop = np.zeros((crop_size_y, crop_size_x, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
image_width = image.shape[1]
image_height = image.shape[0]
xmin_crp, xmax_crp, xmin_img, xmax_img = get_roi_coordinates(offset_width, crop_size_x, image_width)
ymin_crp, ymax_crp, ymin_img, ymax_img = get_roi_coordinates(offset_height, crop_size_y, image_height)
crop[ymin_crp:ymax_crp, xmin_crp:xmax_crp, :] = image[ymin_img:ymax_img, xmin_img:xmax_img, :]


def get_roi_coordinates(rand_offset, crop_width, image_width):
    # No overlap:
    xmin_crp = 0
    xmax_crp = crop_width
    xmin_img = rand_offset
    xmax_img = rand_offset + crop_width

    overlapping_left = xmin_img < 0
    overlapping_right = xmax_img > image_width

    if overlapping_left:
        xmin_crp = np.abs(rand_offset)
        xmin_img = 0

    if overlapping_right:
        xmax_img = image_width
        overlap_right = rand_offset + crop_width - image_width
        xmax_crp = crop_width - overlap_right
    return xmin_crp, xmax_crp, xmin_img, xmax_img
```